# encrypt and decrypt with AESCrypt in android

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I'm developing an app, but I found a problem. I can encrypt but I can not decipher. Can you help me fix it?

the app comes to sensitive data and I would like to send in `Firebase` encrypted data but they remain decrypted on the list.

This is my code:

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText input_tipo, input_id, input_password;
private ListView list_data;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
private List<User> list_users = new ArrayList<>();
private User selectedUser;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private String encryptPass, decryptPass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    Toolbar tool = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tool.setTitle("MySecurity");
    setSupportActionBar(tool);

    input_tipo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipo);
    input_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
    input_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    list_data = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    list_data.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            User user = (User) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            selectedUser = user;

            input_tipo.setText(user.getTipo());
            input_id.setText(user.getId());
            input_password.setText(user.getPassword());

        }
    });


    initFirebase();
    addEventFirebaseListener();
    findNetwork();

}


private void findNetwork() {
    ConnectivityManager CM = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ninfo = CM.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ninfo != null && ninfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connesso in Firebase:" + ninfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connessione internet assente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


private void addEventFirebaseListener() {
    list_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mDatabaseReference.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (list_users.size() > 0)
                list_users.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                list_users.add(user);
            }
            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(UserActivity.this, list_users);
            list_data.setAdapter(adapter);
            list_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


            @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

private void initFirebase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    firebaseAnalytics.setMinimumSessionDuration(5000);
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(mUser.getUid());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_add) {
        createUser();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_remove) {
        deleteUser(selectedUser);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_deselect) {
        DeselectedUser(selectedUser);
    }else if(item.getItemId()== R.id.menu_decrypt){
        DecryptUser(selectedUser);
    }
    return true;
}

private void DecryptUser(User selectedUser) {
    if (selectedUser != null) {
        mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(selectedUser.getUid());

        String password = selectedUser.getPassword().trim();
        String Message= selectedUser.getPassword().trim();

        try {
            decryptPass= AESCrypt.decrypt( password, Message);
            input_tipo.setText(input_tipo.getText().toString());
            input_id.setText(input_id.getText().toString());
            input_password.setText(decryptPass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


private void DeselectedUser(User selectedUser) {
    if (selectedUser != null) {
        mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(selectedUser.getUid());
        clearEditText();
    }
}

private void deleteUser(User selectedUser) {
    if (selectedUser != null) {
        mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(selectedUser.getUid()).removeValue();
        clearEditText();
    }
}


private void createUser() {

    String password = input_password.getText().toString().trim();
    String Message= input_password.getText().toString().trim();

    try {
        encryptPass = AESCrypt.encrypt(password, Message);
        User user1= new User(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), input_tipo.getText().toString(),
                input_id.getText().toString(), encryptPass);
        mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(user1.getUid()).setValue(user1);
        clearEditText();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void clearEditText() {
    input_tipo.setText("");
    input_id.setText("");
    input_password.setText("");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}

}
```

Comment: "I can encrypt but I can not decipher". What happens when you try to decrypt?

Comment: it remains encrypted, the string is not decrypted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `password` and `Message` variables are assigned the same thing (`selectedUser.getPassword().trim()`). What you are doing is trying to decrypt the user password, using the user password. Probably you need to assign the ciphertext that you want to decrypt to the `Message` variable.

Comment: I tried but it gives error, actually I did not understand how to use AESCrypt

Comment: To tell you that for sure, I would like to see your User class. By the code you have posted, it seems that you are not saving the password of the user. However, you are encrypting it using itself as a key (I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by that). Maybe you want to have 2 EditTexts, one for the key and one for the plaintext or ciphertext?

Comment: If you could also post the AESCrypt class, it would be great, as I am not sure what this is doing either.